# Custom Heroku Buildpack with ffmpeg support of libx264

Tags: php, heroku, build, ffmpeg, buildpack

in my **heroku PHP app** I have to use **ffmpeg with libx264** support but found no buildpack that provides libx264 support. So

1. I forked [Heroku Buildpack with ffmpeg support](https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg)
2. Compiled ffmpeg on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 using the steps mentioned [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). (I compiled without -libvpx)
3. Moved the items of ~/bin folder to the bin folder of ~/ffmpeg_build folder and then compressed the ffmpeg_build folder. Uploaded it [here](https://snehasishiiita.github.io/ffmpeg.tar.gz).
4. In my forked rep I updated the [downloaded_url](https://github.com/snehasishroy/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg/blob/master/bin/compile#L10) to my [ffmpeg_build](https://snehasishiiita.github.io/ffmpeg.tar.gz).
5. Created a .buildpacks file with following entry:

https://github.com/snehasishroy/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

Finally I created my heroku app with

> heroku create --buildpack
>   https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

But when I ran heroku run "ffmpeg -version" **error message stated that ffmpeg:command not found**

Can anybody please tell me what mistake I committed? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that https://snehasishroy.github.io/ffmpeg.tar.gz 404s :)

However, be advised that you should be compiling this on Ubuntu 10.04 for 64 bits (or on 14.04 64 bits and use https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/8/19/cedar-14-public-beta)

Comment: Updated my ffmpeg binary link. Thanks for pointing that out. Now I am facing another issue. When I run ffmpeg -version, it states error while loading shared libraries: libva.so

Comment: I think the problem is with the dependencies associated with the ffmpeg binaries. How can I resolve the libva.so error. Can you kindly point me out in the right direction :)

Comment: Solved :) Compiled it on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bits and removed unnecessary dependencies. Also ldd ffmpeg helped a lot :)